# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value Swift

Tags: swift

I want write an extension to `Double` so it func will give `Int` values.

```
extension Double {
  func toPercentage() -> Int {
    var mutableSelf = self
    var twoDigits = Double(round(1000*mutableSelf)/1000)
    return Int(twoDigits) * 100
  }
}
```

On line `var twoDigits = Double(round(1000*mutableSelf)/1000)` compiler throw red -  `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`

But i did reassign self to `mutableSelf` variable. Double is a struct, and it's not reference type, why error appears?

Comment: Try `var mutableSelf = Double(self)`?

Comment: @zaitsman it is an extension to Double, what meaning for Double(self)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are in an extension of `Double`, the compiler infers  `round()` to be the [`mutating func round()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884722-round) method of `Double`, even though the call does not match its signature. This behavior has been reported as a bug:

- [SR-1772 File-level function with the same name as instance function not picked up by compiler](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1772)
- [SR-4660 Methods on self should not block unambiguous calls to free functions](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4660)

You can refer to the global C library function with

```
extension Double {
    func toPercentage() -> Int {
        let twoDigits = Darwin.round(1000*self)/1000
        return Int(twoDigits * 100)
    }
}
```

or better, use the `Double.rounded()` method:

```
extension Double {
    func toPercentage() -> Int {
        let twoDigits = (1000*self).rounded()/1000
        return Int(twoDigits * 100)
    }
}
```

or simply

```
extension Double {
    func toPercentage() -> Int {
        return Int((100 * self).rounded())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Double {
    func toPercentage() -> Int {
        let twoDigits = Double((1000 * self / 1000).rounded())
        return Int(twoDigits) * 100
    }
}
```